# Is there a way to transform data in Stata from a single observation (e.g. # of patients experiencing an event) into many observations?

Tags: statistics, stata

I'm trying to efficiently use Stata to estimate standard errors around a proportion of patients experiencing an adverse event in a model we are adapting. An example dataset:

```
n = 74

a = 56

b = 18
```

Where *n* is the number of patients, *a* is the number of patients experiencing an event and *b* is the number not experiencing an event.

When the data is in this format, I note that using

```
ratio myratio: a/n
```

Returns a proportion (a/n) but does not estimate a linearized standard error. Manually converting the data into "long" format however fixes this issue. Long format being:

```
No. observations = n (74)

n = 1 for all observations

a = 1 if index <= 18 else 0

b = 1 if index > 18 else 0
```

It's been a while since I have used Stata, is there a quick way to do this? I can't even remember how to extend the length of the dataset to the number of samples *N*!

Comment: Ian, a little more information would be helpful. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info for advice about how to add information about your dataset etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may use an immediate command `cii`. Here are two simple examples:

```
. cii proportions 54 18

                                                         -- Binomial Exact --
    Variable |        Obs  Proportion    Std. Err.       [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
             |         54    .3333333      .06415        .2109199     .474745

. cii proportions 54 18, jeffreys

                                                         ----- Jeffreys -----
    Variable |        Obs  Proportion    Std. Err.       [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
             |         54    .3333333      .06415          .21884    .4651605
```

Incidentally, your example method is one where the default "traditional" method often works badly. I support either the `jeffreys` or the `wilson` method as well based. See discussion and references in the manual entry.

Answer (score 1):

The `expand` command may help you convert to "long" format. Check out the documentation (`help expand`). This example, from the documentation, seems most relevent:

```
// load data
webuse stackxmpl, clear

// view original data
list

// Replace each observation with x copies of that observation, where x is the value of b for that observation (note that `b` is a variable in the dataset).
expand b

// List the results
list
```

All you need to do is pass the variable that holds `n` to `expand`

Comment: This is precisely what was asked for and it's a command really worth knowing..